# how to set the position of a element based on it's parent

Tags: jquery, html, css

hi
I have a div which contains just a image like this :

```
(div)
    (img. …)
(/div)
```

Now,I want to create  a mark in the  image  ,s I use :

```
$(div).append((img src =mark.jpg id =mark)).
```

then set its position :

```
$(div img#mark).position(…)
```

Here I don't know how to set it.

I just want   to make the mark's position within its parent .

In fact ,what I want like the google map ,when you search something in google map ,the results will be marked in the map .

Of course,my require is much easy.

I have thought to get the offset of the parent ,then caculate the really position of the mark image .

But I can't make it.  Any idea ?

Btw ,I ask this in my phone ,so I can't make a pretty format.

Comment: Im sorry but I am writing on my phone .I can't see the format bar . And the character(<>) cannot displayed normally,so I use () instead. Sorry -_-

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use CSS:

```
div { position: relative; }
div img#mark { position:absolute; }
```

And then set the position like this:

```
$("div img#mark").css({
    'top': '10px',
    'left': '10px'
});
```

Does that do what you meant?

Answer (score 1):

```
$("div").css('position', 'relative');
$("div img#mark").css({
    position: 'absolute',
    top: '0px',
    left: '0px'
});
```

Change top and left values to suit where you would like to position the mark.

Answer (score 1):

I think you don't need jQuery to do this:

```
div {
  position: relative;
}

img#mark {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
}
```

This way, img#mark will be positioned relative to div's position:

```
+---------------
| div
|    ___________
|   | img#mark
|   |
|   |
|    -----------
|
+---------------
```

Answer (score 1):

If I read you correctly, the desired effect should be achievable with plain css:

```
#container {
  position:relative;
}
#mark {
  position:absolute;
  left: [to your liking] px;
  top: [to your liking] px;
}
```

PS: Oh well, only 3 ppl beat me to it.